# Having multiple buttons in a page

Tags: html, ajax

I am having many submit buttons one for each row in a table. Whenever I click on that button, an Ajax call should be triggered. Right now I am wrapping each button inside a form tag. Is this a good approach? If not, what is a better way to do this. 
Moreover, I will be replacing the button eventually by an image.

Please advise on how to handle this situation.

http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/2077/88405759.png

Comment: What information do you post when you click the button?

Comment: What does that AJAX posting code look like?

Comment: With Ajax involved, you often don't even need a form tag or a submit button.  You use input type=button and assign functions to the onclick event.  I use the form tag when I need to serialize all of the form elements in an ajax post.

Comment: @Fosco: Your idea looks simple and clean. Thanks, will do it..

Comment: @Fosco — Only if you're doing it wrong. http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build

Comment: @David - Hah.  Well, if wrong means excluding people without Javascript, I don't want to be right.

Comment: @Fosco that is the wrong attitude. One example: you will shun users with NoScript.

Comment: @ANeves I don't support the use of NoScript, and think it's quite silly to develop for that segment of users.

Comment: @Fosco My point is not that you have to develop for **all** segments, or that you have to develop for segments that use things that you do not support. (But good luck not developing for IE... I wish I could.) My point is that there will always be surprises and unexpected situations - some caused by the user, some by the service. If you use progressive enhancement, in many cases things will still be usable - just not as pleasant or advanced or comfortable. E.g., if you rely on JS you risk a coding mistake throwing an exception, which will break all the page's functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Right now I am wrapping each button inside a form tag. Is this a good approach?

Yes, this is fine.

The only problem is that the HTML is a little on the chunky side, but that issue is largely eliminated by gzip compression (since there will be a lot of duplicate tokens, which are highly compressible).

In its favour, the method is very simple to implement, very hard to go wrong, and doesn't depend on the user having JavaScript turned on.

You can then, with very little effort, enhance the forms with onsubmit events to use JavaScript to send the data using Ajax and cancel the normal submission of the form.

> Moreover, I will be replacing the button eventually by an image.

I would generally try to avoid that. A button is a clear indicator that it is something clickable that will do something. If you really want to, you can substitute the submit input for an image input.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I went on and further researched about obtrusive and unobtrusive usages. Learnt a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

You can unobtrusively bind a function to a set of elements like this:

```
<script>
var anchors = ​document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].onclick = function() {
        alert(this.id);
        // do ajax call
        return false; 
    }
}​​​
</script>

​<a id="test" href="#">Test</a>
<a id="tes2t" href="#">Test2</a>​
```

Comment: I would create the function in advance, and reuse it: `var submitWithAjax = function() { alert(this.id); return false; }; for(...){anchors[i].onclick = submitWithAjax;}`

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
<input type="button" onclick="AjaxFunction()">
```

where AjaxFunction() is a function which makes ajax-request. The form tag and submit buttons is need not for Ajax requests.

And, by the way, you can use images instead of buttons. Something like this

```
<img src="url" alt=""  onclick="AjaxFunction()" />
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't. You should build on stuff that works and follow the principles of unobtrusive JS. So that means a submit button or, if you really want a graphic, an image input (both of which would be in a form as the question originally suggests).

Comment: @David : I am using Rails and I am not going to write stuff over the onclick function directly as shown by Amber. I will use the specific tags given by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create one big form then differentiate the buttons with their (or other) ids?

Answer (score 0):

You should create one form and put all submit buttons into it. Buttons should have different names.